# Reasoning about functions by examining their type signatures

Tags: function, haskell, types, functional-programming, type-signature

A couple of years ago (2011/2012) I remember stumbling across a paper or a webpage which talked about how in pure functional languages, you can tell a lot about what a function will do just by examining its type signature. Unfortunately after much Googling I haven't stumbled across it again. (Partly because I don't know what search terms to use)

My question is: How much information about a function can you deduce from its type signature?

For massive brownie points: Provide some links to external resources which discuss this or related issues

An example of what I'm looking for: If I remember correctly, a function with the type signature `a -> a` *has to be* the identity function.

Comment: Try searching for “free theorems”.

Comment: You remember [*Theorems for free!*](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html)

Comment: [Descriptive Variable Names: A Code Smell](http://degoes.net/articles/insufficiently-polymorphic) also go into great length on the subject.

Comment: There's a web [generator of free theorems](http://www-ps.iai.uni-bonn.de/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi). Just provide your (polymorphic) types, and you get a theorem back.